# Layout: Images and Text

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, image-processing, pdf-format

I have a lot of images and text that goes with each image. Now I would like to automatically generate the following handout for each pair of image and text:

[image]

- The image is on top.
- The text should be placed below it, its style    should be
  "justified" and if possible hyphenation enabled.
- Then the rest of the space should be an area, with a title names:
  "Notes", to    obviously take notes.

How can I do it with mathematica ?

Here are some images to try:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o8x992dz9gg7q9e/AAAyli1pO2f4q35ULNDreC1ua?dl=0

Here is the sample text that could go with it:

```
text={{"As there are several possibilities to perform lithography,", "I will start by providing some definitions", "and by explaining some general concepts that are recurring for all", "the lithography variations.", "Then I will dive into details how one fabricates the lithography masks", "using a direct write laser tool."},{"Lithography is the fundamental process of transferring geometric shape", "from a design to a thin layer of radiation sensitive material", "called resist.", "Which is covering the surface of a wafer substrate.", "These shapes or patterns define the various regions", "in an integrated circuit, such as the implantation regions,", "the contact windows, the metallic wiring etc."},{"Each lithography follows a well defined series of process steps,","called process flow.", "It may vary according to the lithography used", "and the materials involved.", "But a typical generic example is shown here", "where we go step by step through it.", "First the substrate, it can be a silicon wafer or glass plate,"}}
```

This is what I tried:

```
Labeled[images[[#]], Framed[text[[#]]], 
   LabelStyle -> 
    Directive[Bold, Alignment -> TextJustification, 
     Hyphenation -> False, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]] & /@ 
 Range[Length[images]]
```

Things that I don't know how to do:

1. Adding the extra box for notes
2. A4 size
3. Make image and text appropriate sizes
4. Hyphenation does not seem to work correctly either

UBDATE: New Try...

```
Panel[Grid[{
   {images[[#]], SpanFromLeft},
   {TextCell[Row[{text[[#]] }], TextJustification -> 1, 
     Hyphenation -> False], SpanFromLeft}, {"Notes"}}, Frame -> All], 
 ImageSize -> {210, 297}*2] &/@Range[Length[images]]
```

Gives me: 
[image]

But...

How to make Image/Text an appropriate size ?

Comment: I think tex.stackexchange.com will have better results

Comment: @LCarvalho Thank you for the note, but I am afraid, I would like to do it with Mathematica, not with Latex, if possible.

Comment: This was [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58877/how-to-draw-block-diagrams-as-graph-objects/149604#149604) to another question, see if it helps a little

Comment: You could also generate LaTeX output in a Mathematica program. For example create a template and just replace the image filename and the corresponding description. Would simplify those typesetting issues!

Comment: @M.Stern Thanks for the input. This is a good idea, however, as there are really a lot of images to process, I would prefer something completly automatic, but maybe less pretty.

Comment: @M.Stern I got it to work, after a lot of trial and error ! See my answer...

Comment: @totyped See this: [Answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152663/making-a-website-with-mathematica/152779#152779)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error:

```
  Panel[Style[Grid[{
          {images[[#]], SpanFromLeft},
          {TextCell[Row[{text[[#]]}], TextJustification -> 1, 
            Hyphenation -> False], SpanFromLeft}, {"Notes"}}, 
         Frame -> {{False, False, True, True}, {True, True, True, True}}, 
         BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1], 7, 
        FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], ImageSize -> {210, 297}*2] & /@ 
     Range[Length[slides]]
```

[image]